# When I was learning the Bézier curve, this curve was not change to what I expected

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, bezier, cubic-bezier

```kotlin
data class DragStatus(
    //是否正在拖动
    val onDrag: Boolean = false,
    //拖动大于一定距离，气泡消失
    val onDragComplete: Boolean = false
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    companion object {
        const val RADIUS = 30f
        const val MIN_DRAG_DISTANCE = 110
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var controlX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var controlY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var sin by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var cos by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var circleStartX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var circleStartY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var bubbleEndX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var bubbleEndY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var bubbleStartX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var bubbleStartY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var circleEndX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var circleEndY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var dragStatus by remember {
                mutableStateOf(DragStatus())
            }
            var circleRadius by remember { mutableStateOf(RADIUS) }
            val bubbleRadius by remember { mutableStateOf(RADIUS) }
            var minDragDistance by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            var previousDistance by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                Canvas(modifier = Modifier.offset(), onDraw = {
                    //消息数量的圆
                    //什么时候圆显示：1.拖动没超过一定距离
                    if (!dragStatus.onDragComplete) {
                        drawCircle(Color.Red, circleRadius)
                    }
                })
                val path = Path()
                Canvas(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectDragGestures(
                                onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                                    offsetX += dragAmount.x
                                    offsetY += dragAmount.y
                                    minDragDistance = sqrt(
                                        (offsetX
                                            .toDouble()
                                            .pow(2.0) + offsetY
                                            .toDouble()
                                            .pow(2.0)).toFloat()
                                    )
                                    if (minDragDistance > previousDistance) {
                                        circleRadius -= ((minDragDistance - previousDistance) / 5)
                                    } else if (minDragDistance < previousDistance) {
                                        circleRadius += ((previousDistance - minDragDistance) / 5)
                                    }
                                    previousDistance = minDragDistance
                                    dragStatus = dragStatus.copy(onDrag = true)
                                },
                                onDragEnd = {
                                    dragStatus = dragStatus.copy(onDrag = false)
                                    if (minDragDistance < MIN_DRAG_DISTANCE) {
                                        offsetX = 0f
                                        offsetY = 0f
                                    } else {
                                        dragStatus = dragStatus.copy(onDragComplete = true)

                                    }
                                    minDragDistance = 0f
                                    circleRadius = RADIUS
                                }
                            )
                        }, onDraw = {
                        path.reset()
                        if (dragStatus.onDrag) {
                            //画可以拖动的圆
                            drawCircle(Color.Green, bubbleRadius)
                            //画两个圆之间的连接效果
                            controlX = (offsetX + 0) / 2
                            controlY = (offsetY + 0) / 2
                            sin = offsetY / minDragDistance
                            cos = offsetX / minDragDistance
                            circleStartX = circleRadius * sin - 0f
                            circleStartY = 0f - circleRadius * cos
                            bubbleEndX = offsetX + bubbleRadius * sin
                            bubbleEndY = offsetY - bubbleRadius * cos
                            bubbleStartX = offsetX - bubbleRadius * sin
                            bubbleStartY = offsetY + bubbleRadius * cos
                            circleEndX = 0f - circleRadius * sin
                            circleEndY = 0f + circleRadius * cos
                            println(
                                "------------------------------\noffsetX: $offsetX offsetY: $offsetY \n" +
                                        "controlX: $controlX controlY: $controlY\nminDragDistance: $minDragDistance\nsin: $sin cos: $cos\n" +
                                        "circleStartX: $circleStartX circleStartY: $circleStartY\nbubbleEndX: $bubbleEndX bubbleEndY: $bubbleEndY\n" +
                                        "bubbleStartX: $bubbleStartX bubbleStartY: $bubbleStartY\ncircleEndX: $circleEndX circleEndY: $circleEndY\n" + "------------------------------\n"
                            )
                            path.moveTo(-circleStartX, -circleStartY)
                            path.quadraticBezierTo(-controlX, -controlY, -bubbleEndX, -bubbleEndY)
                            path.lineTo(-bubbleStartX, -bubbleStartY)
                            path.quadraticBezierTo(-controlX, -controlY, -circleEndX, -circleEndY)
                            path.close()
                            drawPath(path, Color.Green)
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Current effects]

I used two different colors to distinguish. Now, one canvas has drawn a circle, the other canvas has drawn a circle that can be dragged, and the path connecting two circles. When I drag the green circle, the radius of the red circle gradually decreases. The left two points of the green part should have been on the radius of the small circle. I printed the log and found that the values of (circleStartX, circleStartY) (circleEndX, circleEndY) have indeed changed, But the UI did not change due to the reduction of the radius of the red circle, and it remained in its original position

The above is all the code, and the effect is that when I move the red dot, there is a connection effect between the moving red dot and the origin. The above code can be run directly, please help me find the problem. Thank you. The current effect is problematic, and it took me a long time to find any issues. I am too foolish.
The current effect is that when I drag the red dot, I change the values of the start and end points, and the printing did indeed change, but the effect drawn by path did not change. I called path. reset() but it was unsuccessful, and I couldn't find the problem.
My ultimate goal is to achieve this effect: similar to a message bubble, when I drag over a certain distance, the bubble will disappear. At present, I have not achieved the remaining results and have encountered difficulties. All the English in the question comes from machine translation. I'm not sure if you can understand my question

Comment: Note that you code isn't an [mcve] yet, it's missing the imports and minimal wrapper code to just work. You'll also want to fix the indentation a bit, because code does not have the luxury of lots of space, regardless of personal preferences, in order for folks to see the most of your code you generally want to use two space indentation when putting the code in your post.

Comment: I just made some modifications. Can you take a look at this? I'm not particularly familiar with the use of some features on this website. I'm sorry
@Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans

Comment: Might be worth (re)reading the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and some of the common [help center](/help) topics to (re)familiarize yourself with what's available - I haven't done any Android development so I'm not the right person to help solve this problem, but with a true [mcve] hopefully others can now jump in and pinpoint where things are going wrong for you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will carefully read the release guide again